# Huawei Themes, error when trying to upload theme submission

Tags: themes, lockscreen, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm trying to upload a lock screen theme to Huawei Themes, and I keep getting error "The designer name in the upload package does not match the information in the designer information." I'm not sure what's wrong here or what I'm supposed to put for the "Designer" field in the package settings, as the documentation does not provide this information. I set both the Designer and Developer fields as my Developer name. What should the Designer value actually be?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and it's honestly really confusing. I found out that the designer nickname is actually your Huawei ID nickname.
[image]